# Store partial results in dask delayed iterations

Tags: python, loops, dask

I have a current long iteration process where I run a calculation and every `x` iteration I store the results to DB.

For example, iterate `fun()` function over `range(20)` and save every 5 results with `save_results`:

```
import time

def fun(x):
    time.sleep(0.1*x)
    return(0.1*x)

def save_results(result):
    # originally stores the new data to DB
    print result  # print as example

result = []
for i in range(20):
    result.append(fun(i))
    if i%5==4:
        save_results(result[-5:])
```

I want to parallelize the process with `dask` `delayed` and `compute` methods. But if I run it like in the following example, the `store_results` occurs before the `compute`:

```
import dask as da

result = []
for i in range(20):
    result.append(da.delayed(fun)(i))
    if i%5==4:
        save_results(result[-5:])

result = da.compute(result)[0]
```

and therefore, instead of storing the results every 5 iterations, I store a list of delayed objects:

> ```
> [Delayed('fun-202f7e28-e594-4926-a5cd-5931dbc99d6b'),
> Delayed('fun-d2bf2bc9-a4f3-46d7-adb7-84114a68b482'),
> Delayed('fun-c34f2c04-3e25-47fa-8165-1ee7c786aaf6'),
> Delayed('fun-a4edd3fc-442d-4ec1-8a0e-320bd9315a61'),
> Delayed('fun-c7b48e2c-cb66-472e-85c5-fe6c595fa1ec')]
> ```

How can I overcome the issue, and store every 5 new results to DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should delay any function calls that operate on delayed objects

#### Sequential code

```
result = []
for i in range(20):
    result.append(fun(i))
    if i%5==4:
        save_results(result[-5:])
```

#### Parallel code

```
def fun(x):
    ...

result = []
side_effects = []
for i in range(20):
    result = dask.delayed(fun)(i)
    results.append(result)
    if i%5==4:
        value = dask.delayed(save_results)(result[-5:])
        side_effects.append(value)

dask.compute(results + side_effects)
```

Comment: What would be the order of the execution? Which 5 results will be stored each time?

Comment: The term "order of execution" stops making sense in a parallel environment, but the dependencies you've laid out are explicit.  This will `save_results` on the results of 0..4, 5..9, 10..14, etc..

Comment: Thanks! What if there are dependices between the jobs? Will dask know to calculate them correctly itself?

Comment: You encode dependencies when you supply one delayed result to another delayed call.  See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html